# i18n setting global interpolation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I'm using [i18n interpolation](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax.html#interpolations) to render `non-breaking hyphen` (html code: `&#8209;`) in my translations:

**`component`**:

```
{{ $t('message', {char: '&#8209;'}) }}
```

**`en.json`**:

```
"message": "I am working full{char}time on this project."
```

I would like to do that for every translation in my project without having to pass `char` parameter to each translation. Is there a way to set `char = &#8209` globally in `i18n` and pass it to all translations without having to specify it each time?

Here's my **`i18n.js`** setup file:

```
import {createI18n} from 'vue-i18n';


function loadLocaleMessages() {

    const pathsGlob = import.meta.glob('../../lang/*.json')

    const messages = {}

    for (const path in pathsGlob) {
        pathsGlob[path]().then((mod) => {
            const locale = path.split('/')[path.split('/').length - 1].split('.')[0]
            messages[locale] = mod
        })
    }
    return messages
}


export default new createI18n({
    locale: navigator.language.substring(0, 2),
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
    silentTranslationWarn: true,
    silentFallbackWarn: true,
});
```

Comment: Consider providing your own `$t` and `i18n.t` that wraps around the original and provides this param

Comment: @EstusFlask do you know of a source of how to use `i18n.t`?

Comment: Here's the signature, https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#composertranslation . Basically something like `t = (...args) => { if (args.length <= 2) return i18n.t(args[0], { char: '!', ...args[1] }) else if (args.length === 3) ...`. Since `t` now replaces `tc`, etc, it has variable amount of args

Comment: Seems to be complex. I'll have to take some time off to work myself into it. Thank you